# How to use Oracle DMP files?

Tags: oracle, database-backups

I have some files of an Oracle database with username and password.

How do I connect to all files and browse the data tables and fields. I want to view all my records in them. Do I install Oracle Database server? Or is there a tool on internet to connect with my all files and browse data?

=== Files have .dmp extension ===

Comment: This question is unclear.  Oracle does not have Office files.  What is the extension of the files you have?  .dmp  .dbf  or what?

Comment: @kevinsky : Office mean Work Office (Job). and files have ".dmp" extension.

Answer (score 8):

Oracle .dmp files can only be read by Oracle tools.  Try installing the free [oracle 10g express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) and use the [import command](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ).  Or you can use [SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) which is installed by default with Oracle 10g express or can be downloaded and installed separately.
 Either way you need to import the files to an Oracle database to view the files easily.

Comment: sir, Thanks for giving the references for importing and exporting the dmp files.

Answer (score 4):

Those .dmp files are data dumps used for [backup and recovery](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ). You don't use them as is, but re-import them in your Oracle DBMS.

Comment: if these are recovery files, then which are the files that what i want.

Comment: Oracle doesn't work with files directly. You got a server and a driver to communicate with it. How the data is stored doesn't matter, you don't use those files directly.

Comment: i hava a large folder of 1.16GB of data with alot of extensions including [*.fmx , *.rep , *.DMP ].. i am working with MySQL database. i have no idea for Oracle. So can your tell me solution.

Comment: I thought I already did. .dmp are files to import. .fmx are for Oracle forms. All these files can only be used with the right Oracle tools. But Oracle is not the kind of DBMS you just install in a minute. You got some reading to do. I cannot explain in two sentences what needs to be done. Usually you hire a $200 and hour DBA to install this stuff for you.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to get your data

1. Install an oracle database
2. Import the dmp files you had

You can query the data using sql with username and password.