# Converting .dmp to .sql file for importing in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I have a file called post.dmp file . I have to import that file into postgresql to access that data. Please help me how to go forward

Comment: Isn't that an Oracle dump file?

Comment: I got the file from online for a use case. i don't know what type (oracle/or any other) it is.

Comment: If you don't know, how should we know? ;)  What makes you think that it's a Postgres format?

Comment: Are you saying that .dmp files can be dealt with only oracle? please suggest me . I am new to it

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326712/how-to-use-oracle-dmp-files .

Comment: So from what i understood is that .dmp extension can be dealt with only oracle right? correct me if i a am wrong

Comment: dmp is commonly associated with Oracle dump files, not with Postgres database backups/dumps/whatever. I would have thought that the only source where you got the file would have given more info or even instructions on how to handle the file.

Comment: Thanks for the info